# how to change boot device from pen drive to hard disk

Tags: installation

i have installed ubuntu from a bootable pen drive. The installation is complete and is working well... how can i change my primary boot device from pen drive to hard disk?

Comment: This is normally done in the computer's Setup (usually accessed by pressing F2). What happens if you just remove the pen drive? dose the computer boot from hard disk correctly?

Comment: That depends on your PC model.However,if you have unattached the pen-drive,then it should boot from Hard disk anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows (nevermind the page title, the procedure for installing the bootloader is the same)

In short, you need to open a terminal window and type

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

but be sure to read the whole article I linked to.